# How do I change colors in Zim (wiki editor) running on Kubuntu 18.10?

Tags: kubuntu, gtk, colors

These are the colors present in Zim which uses GTK

[image: Zim colors]

How can I change them to more of my liking? The color for links is very hard to read on the dark Breeze theme.

Kubuntu 18.10 (Kernel: 4.18.0-17-generic) & Zim (0.68) installed via terminal

Comment: @DKBose Alright I've added those details!

Comment: The reason I asked about *how* you installed Zim, is that some users install snaps/flatpaks and the appearance, in such cases, maybe difficult to alter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm still on Kubuntu 18.04 but it appears that the version of *Zim* is the same in 18.10.

- *Zim* seems to be a *gtk2* application
- Kubuntu allows users to choose different *gtk2* and *gtk3* (and *qt*) themes.
- Open *System Settings > Application Style > GNOME Application Style* and make your selections there. **However**, certain aspects of *Zim*'s appearance are **not** governed by the *gtk2* theme.
- *Zim*'s *Help > FAQ* mentions that a user can

> ### … change the colors used for links, underline etc. ?
>
> Copy "/usr/share/zim/style.conf" to "~/.config/zim/" and edit as you
>   see fit. See the Config Files page for the syntax of this file.

That allows users to modify several aspects of *Zim*'s appearance, including links.

To get the image below, I edited my *~/.config/zim/style.conf* to change the link color from *blue* to *aquamarine*.

[image: Changing Zim's link color to aquamarine from blue]

Comment: "To get the image below, I edited my ~/.config/zim/style.conf to change the link color from blue to aquamarine." That's all I needed! Thank you so much!! I thought, this would be the end for me and this wonderful knowledgebase/notepad software ... can't believe, they didn't wrote about this in the github discussion here https://github.com/zim-desktop-wiki/zim-desktop-wiki/issues/755

anyway, thanks! I'll note that trick instantly ... in my new knowledgebase software ;)